# Auto-start in install4J

Tags: install4j

Is there an integrated feature that will enable me to auto-start the program after Install4J installer is finished? Ideally to add "Start after installation is finished" button.

I see that there is field "Post-activation script" property on the finish form in the installer, but not sure if this can be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add an "Execute launcher" action to your "Finish screen". When you do that, the install4j IDE will also ask you if you want to add a confirmation question to the finish screen.